# no outcomes when trying to recover files with testdisk

Tags: testdisk

I've been trying to recover files with Testdisk and lately, it stopped working. on the outcome, it shows "Copy done! 0 ok, 0 failed"
how do I fix it?
[image]

Comment: See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: I've been using it before for a very long time and it was working fine. it's not really about the steps I take

Comment: It may be because the filename that you highlight has ", " in it.

Comment: it's not, I just tried it now with a different file.

Comment: You're selecting the desired file with ":", yes? What destination directory is it trying to write to?

Comment: yes, I tried copying the files to any file inside Desktop, Documents and Pictures.  i still got the same results

Comment: Are those destinations r/w or r/o? I assume that you're booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, yes? And you're selecting files with ":"? What if you select a destination like a flash key?

Comment: The destination is "Home/user/Desktop/Folder...   I always used this method or similar.

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to write to a disk/destination that's on the disk that you're trying to recover from. You risk overwriting the deleted file that you're trying to recover. If the drive has errors, it's probably in r/o mode. Have you run `fsck` on the Ubuntu partition? Does the copy work when the destination is a flash key, or some other writable device?

Comment: oh thank. it works when i recover from driver flash drive. but does not work the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

The user was having trouble copying deleted files, because the hard disk was being mounted as read only, either due to file system errors, or other mount command. User was trying to write to the source disk using `testdisk`.

To check for file system errors...

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

To recover deleted files using `testdisk`, do **NOT** write the files to the same disk as the source disk. Select a different destination, like an external USB HDD or flash drive.

Comment: thank you so much. i well understood